# Problem to get old series data (Python for Finance)

Tags: python, finance, quantitative-finance

I've converted this formula (**ZLEMA Moving Average**)

[image]

But I have many issues with "Data(Lag Days Ago)", it seems that it cant go back to find the result. Here's the function but unfortunately it doesn't produce the desired result.

```
def fzlema(source,period):
  zxLag     = period / 2 if (period / 2) == np.round(period / 2) else (period - 1) / 2
  zxLag     = int(zxLag) 
  zxEMAData = source + (source - source.iloc[zxLag])  # Probably error is in this line
  zlema     = zxEMAData.ewm(span=period, adjust=False).mean()
  zlema     = np.round(zlema,2)
  return zlema

zlema =  fzlema(dataframe['close'], 50)
```

To be clear, the script runs perfectly but what I got is unmatched as it's been calculated on Tradingview.
I tried used `iloc[..]` and `tail(..)` but neither return exact results.
I can use the libraries `pandas` and `numpy`.

Any point of view?

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:

Simply using `source.shift(zxLag)`